# Что означает восклицательный знак в git alias команде?

Tags: git

Есть git alias команда `ac = !git add -A && git commit`,
что означает знак ! перед словом git и почему второй git без этого знака ?

Если есть ресурсы объясняющие  alias знаки буду рад  посмотреть.

Comment: Есть ресурсы. Документация называется. Это не считая гугла.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-Git https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ man git-config
...
       If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it
       will be treated as a shell command.
```

мой вольный перевод:

> если содержимое псевдонима начинается с восклицательного знака, оно трактуется как команда оболочки.

добавлю неочевидное (что изложено в первоисточнике абзацем выше): иначе (т.е. без восклицательного знака) содержимое псевдонима трактуется как список аргументов для вызова программы *git*.